# are multiple action performed methods needed when using multiple JButtons/JRadioButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jradiobutton

My question is basically just the title, but I have a button in my code that makes some JRadiobuttons appear, do I then need to make another action performed method and give it a different name or something? Nothing happens when I use the same action performed method.

so like:

````
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

        if( a.getSource() == button1 ) {

      System.out.println("hi");
      }
}
  @Override
  public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent b){
    if(b.getSource()==firstJRadioButton){
        System.out.println("hi there");
    }
    
  }```

The code above gives me an error and is not my exact code, but I hope it sort of says what I am trying to do if that makes sense.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to put your real working code in a question.

The short answer is that you need to make another `ActionListener` *object*, *with* another `actionPerformed` method, or adapt your single `actionPerformed` method to handle *all* your components.

An `ActionListener` is an instance of a class which implements the `ActionListener` interface, so you can only have one action listener per class.

This means that there are two ways of handling the actions of multiple components:

###### Have a single `ActionListener` instance and then check which component has performed the action:

```
public class ListenerEg extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public ListenerEg() throws HeadlessException {
        this.button1 = new JButton("button 1");
        this.button2 = new JButton("button 2");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        this.pack();
    }
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ListenerEg().setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            System.out.println("Button 1");
        } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            System.out.println("Button 2");
        }
    }
}
```

###### Have an `ActionListener` for each component. This is a better approach, as your `ActionListener` implementation doesn't end up with all your code in it.

```
public class ListenerEg extends JFrame {

    public ListenerEg() throws HeadlessException {
        this.button1 = new JButton("button 1");
        this.button2 = new JButton("button 2");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Button 1");
        });
        this.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Button 2");
        });
        this.pack();
    }
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ListenerEg().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You don't have to use a lambda for the `ActionListener`, you might create your own class hierarchy of `ActionListener` implementations to reuse common code and improve testability:

```
public class ListenerEg extends JFrame {
    private final JButton button1;
    private final JButton button2;

    public ListenerEg() throws HeadlessException {
        this.button1 = new JButton("button 1");
        this.button2 = new JButton("button 2");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
        this.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
        this.pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ListenerEg().setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(b.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

(these are not best practice Swing programs, just the shortest way to illustrate this point)